# Thrift::TException=HASH(0x25d18e0) error

Tags: perl, hadoop, hive

I am trying to connect to Hive via Perl module Thrift::API::HiveClient and below is the code to connect to Hadoop hive and retrieve the data

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use DBI;
use DBI::DBD;
use Data::Dumper;
use List::MoreUtils qw(uniq);
use DateTime;
#use warnings 'all';
use POSIX qw(strftime);
use LWP::Simple;
use Thrift;
use Thrift::API::HiveClient;
use Data::Dumper;

my $latest_return;

# Database connection
my $client = Thrift::API::HiveClient->new(
     host    => 'localhost',
    port    => '10000',
);
$client->connect or die "Could not connect";

my $rh = $client->execute('select * from devtest.users');
my $return = [];
while ($latest_return = $client->fetch($rh)) { # will die with an error if it fails
    print $latest_return;
}
```

When I execute the above script it throws below message

Thrift::TException=HASH(0x25d18e0)

I also tried Dumper to print the result nothing got printed.

any help is much appreciated.

Comment: We don't have enough information. All that tells us is that your `fetch` is returning an `Thrift::TException` object. Given the module description suggests it's "alpha" quality, then I'm not sure we can do much to help.

Comment: @Sobrique this is stderr Thrift::TException=HASH(0x1911438) (in cleanup) Thrift::TException=HASH(0x2869a78) at (eval 144) line 31, <DATA> line 1.

Comment: @Sobrique 31st line $client->connect or die "Could not connect";
in my code

Comment: Please *always* add `use strict` and `use warnings 'all'` to the top of every Perl program you write, especially before you ask for help to fix it. I see that you have chosen to comment out `use warnings 'all'`, so presumably you have had warnings that you didn't like and chose to disable them instead of fixing the problem. That is a lazy and unprofessional approach, and you really should do better before you ask the world what is wrong with what you have written.

Comment: @Borodin I missed copying that actually, usually my Perl binaries path are from different path usually

Comment: @Tagar can you send me the working code here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so the problem here is - you're doing something that's failing.
The module you import - [`Thrift::API::Hiveclient`](http://search.cpan.org/~sscaffidi/Thrift-API-HiveClient-0.003/lib/Thrift/API/HiveClient.pm) warns:

> THIS CODE IS ALPHA-QUALITY, EXPERIMENTAL, AND LIKELY FLAMMABLE

Having said that - what is happening here, is for some the action is failing, and it's `die`ing with an error object.

That error object has status code and message with it. (I don't think this is idomatic perl though, it's more like Java :)).

So in the `connect` there's an error, that's not being handled properly so your code is dying.

A [`Thrift::TException`](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/JKING/Thrift-0.9.3/lib/Thrift.pm) is a fairly simple sort of object:

```
package Thrift::TException;

sub new {
    my $classname = shift;
    my $self = {message => shift, code => shift || 0};

    return bless($self,$classname);
}
1;
```

Literally just a message and a code.

To get at that message, you'll need to dereference your object, and that's what doesn't seem to be happening.

My best guess is the `_open` method in [`Thrift::Socket`](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/JKING/Thrift-0.9.3/lib/Thrift/Socket.pm) is returning an error, and the HiveClient isn't actually trapping/handling it.

It *should* be doing an `eval` and trapping the error, and then unpacking the TException.

Somewhere here:

```
sub connect {
  my ($self) = @_;
  $self->_transport->open;
}
```

Maybe. I'm not 100% sure, because `Moo` might do something cute with `die`, but I can't find or see where that is.

So short answer - you're probably failing to connect, to be sure you'd need to grab that error message - to do that you'll need to hack the `Hiveclient` to eval the operation. This is what you signed up for by using a module that's "Alpha quality".